# Adding onPress event handlers to already existing Buttons (event listener?)

Tags: react-native, onclicklistener

I have already written code for a mobile app in react native that has A LOT of buttons. I want to modify an onPress event for every single one of them by adding an additional function.

So, say my buttons do different things, but when each one of them is clicked, I want to log that that particular button was clicked.

How can I do this without modifying each of the onPress events separately?

Is there something similar to document.addEventListener but for mobile applications?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to detect which button was pressed without modifying the already existing functions.

You can create a "global" function for the buttons, where all of them pass and then calls the actual button. For example:

```
onPressHandler=(buttonPressedFunction)=>{
    //Do what you need
    buttonPressedFunction()   
}

firstButtonClick=()=>{
    //first button click function   
}
secondButtonClick=()=>{
    //second button click function   
}


//render

<Button title="first button" onPress={()=>{this.onPressHandler(this.firstButtonClick)}}/>

<Button title="second button" onPress={()=>{this.onPressHandler(this.secondButtonClick)}}/>
```

Still have to modify the onPress on every button but at least it passes trough a single function, making the button click function still independent

Answer (score 0):

You can send a different parameter for each button as follows:

```
onPressButtonHandler = (key, event) => {
     if(key == ‘one’){
     // your code here.
     }
     if( key == ‘two’){
     // code two here.
     }
}
```

In your render function:

```
<button onPress={this.onPressButtonHandler.bind(this, ‘one’)}>One</button>
 <button onPress={this.onPressButtonHandler.bind(this, ‘two’)}>Two</button>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without modifying the existing onPress method? Say, by adding a listener? Essentially, I am trying to find the equivalent of document.addEventListener('click') but for react native mobile app